# Application vanishes when trying to invoke an OLEDB provider with VB6 Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports, oledb

I have to use an OLEDB provider (for Sungard Investran) from my crystal reports in Winforms Application. Using .Net 4, Crystal Reports for VS2010. The OLEDB Provider has a Parameters Dialog, which I believe is developed in VB6. When I call this OLEDB provider with Queries without any Parameters, it works fine. But when calling any Query with Parameters, the entire application just vanishes. Everything Works fine on Windows XP but has this issue in Windows 7. The app is compiled for x86 platform only. Tries with "all platforms" too, same issue.
I see two errors in the Windows Event Log

*** Error 1**

> Application: MyApplication.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 071116C0

****Error 2 ****

> Faulting application name: MyApplication.exe, version: 1.1.2009.130,
>   time stamp: 0x4e7b4051 Faulting module name: unknown, version:
>   0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault
>   offset: 0x071116c0 Faulting process id: 0xa14 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01cc793091b8b5b0 Faulting application path:
>   C:\MYApp\MyApp\bin\x86\Debug\MyApplication.exe Faulting module path:
>   unknown Report Id: d351c329-e523-11e0-a2de-0023240631a8

Any Pointers to Fix this issue is highly Appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried running it with elevated privileges under Win 7 to see if that eliminates the problem?

Comment: Yes.. Tried and getting the error even with Elevated privileges and also tried various compatibility options available on Windows 7.

Comment: Are you able to use the OLEDB provider in the Server Manager in visual studio?

Comment: YES. The OLEDB Provider works normally when there is no need to invoke the parameters dialog. But Visual Studio also disappears when the the parameter dialog tries to show up.

Comment: So I would say this is a problem with the provider, and there's probably nothing much you can do about it.

Comment: Agreed, contact the vendor for support.

Comment: Is there any way we can allow the application to execute code in the UNSAFE mode, or something like that, so that the component can work?

Comment: The Provider apparently is fine. As OLEDB providers are typically developed using Win32 or ATL. the issue is now with several OLEDB providers, including SAP/BW which has UI. Most of the Microsoft provided OLEDB providers doesn't have UI and works fine. Again these providers are working fine when used from Excel, but fails when used in any .Net Application (only when the UI need to be invoked). Under this circumstances, it is hard to finger point at Vendor, as they run the typical test, using it in Excel and it works there. Appreciate any help in this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution hard way. We need to set uiaccess=true in the manifest. Guidance is provided on this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssecurity/thread/4d2e1358-af95-4f4f-b239-68ec7e2525a9/). Caveat is that it is very annoying as there are lot of restrictions around this solution. But it works though. Welcome to the world of x64.

Thank you all who showed interest in this issue and tried to find a solution for me. And I am proud to be part of this community who cares for each of us.