# Crystal Reports for VS 2010 or 2008 - ActiveX Control - How to Use?

Tags: winforms, activex, crystal-reports-2010

I am trying to use Crystal Reports ActiveX Viewer 13 from within Winforms. While SAP/BO has said they are not going to support this but I see the ActiveX control available on the machine. Any idea on how to use this control? 
The Problem i'm facing with the the .Net Viewer is that it crashes on Windows7 if the OLEDB provider has any UI like parameters dialog. I posted the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517147/application-vanishes-when-trying-to-invoke-an-oledb-provider-with-vb6-form) separately. One of the friend solved this issue by using Cr11R2 ActiveX Viewer. I am trying to find if it is possible to solve the issue by using the ActiveX Viewer that Comes wit CR for VS2010.

Any pointers in this direction is appreciated.

**Found the Answer - The ActiveX control is still available for use with Webprojects. None of the supporting files to run on a Winforms application are avaialble so .. I guess one cannot use this option anymore**

Comment: Contact the vendor for support.  Or take a hint.

Comment: That's Exactly the problem. Vendor's response is that it is not supported and should get a license of BO Enterprise to use that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ActiveX control is still available for use with Webprojects. None of the supporting files to run on a Winforms application are avaialble so .. I guess one cannot use this option anymore